# Can you please let me know the code to capture the status codes other than 200 in network tab in browser in selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium, networking, browser

My application has multiple pages and i want to write a code to capture the status other than 200 in the network tab of the browser. I want to do this using Selenium and Python

It will be helpful if you can share this

Answer (score 1):

**selenium 4:**

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver

import json

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

options.set_capability("goog:loggingPrefs", {  # old: loggingPrefs
    "performance": "ALL"})

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    options=options
)

driver.get("https://www.google.com")
sleep(5)

# returns a list of all events
logs = driver.get_log("performance")


#iterate through the list
for log in logs:
    #converting the string to dict
    a= json.loads(log['message'])

    #get the resolved requests and get the response content from it
    if "Network.responseReceived" == a['message']["method"]:
        print(a["message"]["params"]["response"]["url"])
        print(a["message"]["params"]["response"]["status"])

        #you can see the full request object in the demofile2.txt created in your current directory
        f = open("demofile2.txt", "a")
        f.write(json.dumps(a, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

**selenium 3**

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver

import json

caps = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
#as per latest docs
caps['goog:loggingPrefs'] = {'performance': 'ALL'}
driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=caps)

driver.get("https://www.google.com")
sleep(5)

# returns a list of all events
logs = driver.get_log("performance")


#iterate through the list
for log in logs:
    #converting the string to dict
    a= json.loads(log['message'])

    #get the resolved requests and get the response content from it
    if "Network.responseReceived" == a['message']["method"]:
        print(a["message"]["params"]["response"]["url"])
        print(a["message"]["params"]["response"]["status"])

        #you can see the full request object in the demofile2.txt created in your current directory
        f = open("demofile2.txt", "a")
        f.write(json.dumps(a, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

**you can log PERFORMANCE log and then get the Network.receivedresponse events**

Comment: Thanks for sharing this... It worked for me.. Have a good day

Comment: please accept the answer by clicking the tick sign  :) Thank you